# Can you marry other players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-comes-alive

My friends and I are doing a server roleplay and we have the 1.12.2 version of MCA. Me and one friend want to marry each other but we don't know how to. Can you marry other players? If so, then how?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [MCA github](https://github.com/WildBamaBoy/minecraft-comes-alive/blob/1.12.2-6.0.1/src/main/java/mca/command/CommandMCA.java) to get married you use the command `/mca propose <PlayerName>`.

Comment: @Joachim the tags on the question states that this question refers to the mod Minecraft comes alive, I looked at the GitHub as I could find a reference to a proposal command but couldn't find what that command was

Comment: You're right, didn't catch that immediately :)